# What does $f \lor g$ mean where $f,g$ are functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, notation

I've encountered a problem asking me to prove that $f \lor g$ is lower-semi-comtinuous if $f,g$ are so. But I don't know what $f\lor g$ means... Any answer would be appreciated!

Comment: Not seen that. Where'd you encounter the problem? Any context?

Comment: @runway44 A textbook written by my teacher, but in Chinese.

Comment: I have seen $\lor$ used to mean the maximum and $\land$ used to mean the minimum before, which means appropriate here given that you're looking at lower semi-continuity.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet This probably makes sense. I’ll try. Thanks!

Comment: I made a typo. Please replace "which means appropriate" with "which seems appropriate".

Comment: The title of the question made it sound like you wanted all meanings, but the body makes it clear you want the meaning in this one specific context. This notation has [a completely unrelated meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum#Examples) in topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This notation comes from [lattice theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)), where $\wedge$ means meet (i.e., greatest lower bound) and $\vee$ means join (i.e., least upper bound). In this context, $f \vee g$ is the function given by the pointwise maximum of $f$ and $g$, while $f \wedge g$ is their pointwise minimum.

(Personally, I don't know why some people prefer this notation over the clearer $\min(f,g)$ and $\max(f,g)$; the symbols look like they're pointing the wrong way to me. $f \vee g$ points *down*, but it means *maximum*.)

Comment: The notation $\vee$ should be compared to $\cup$ (and similarly $\wedge$ to $\cap$), I am not sure about your comparison with "up and down".

Comment: @PedroTamaroff What I mean is that $\vee$ is a downward-pointing arrow, so it pictorially suggests "minimum" to me, when in fact it means "maximum."

Answer (score 2):

The notation you are searching for is: $ f \lor g = \dfrac{f+g+|f-g|}{2}$. Can you manage to define the $f \land g$ ?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, this means the maximum $\max(f,g)$ between $f$ and $g$. The notation is common when dealing with [posets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet), where $x\vee y$ is called the "join" of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

The notation $a \lor b$ means the maximum of $a$ and $b$. $a \land b$ means the minimum of $a$ and $b$.

This explanation is mnemonic; from a historical perspective it is not accurate.

There are many ways to remember this and explain the choice of symbol, but I like thinking of the minimum and maximum reading of $\land$ and $\lor$ as generalizations of their meaning in logic.

If we think of classical logic and use $0$ to mark false and $1$ to mark true, then $a \;\text{or}\; b$ the maximum of $a$ and $b$. This means we can think of the maximum in general as a generalization of $\lor$. The case for $\land$ is analogous.